# Attractive when it's in gravy (7)

Tags: cryptic-clues

How's my first cryptic clue?

> Attractive when it's in gravy (7)

Comment: Oh, I don't know about you, but *chicken* in gravy is pretty damn attractive to me.

Comment: A question mark in the clue should suffice, for me.

Comment: @Phylyp I don't know, that sounds a paltry answer (!)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's quite a nice and gettable clue:

> GRAVITY (IT is in GRAVY) is attractive

But a couple of comments:

> "When" doesn't quite work as a joining word for me, and some people might not like "attractive" as a definition (though gravity is attractive, attractive is not gravity).

EDIT: Similar clue (not quite the same):

> According to [wordplays.com](https://www.wordplays.com/crossword-solver/the-importance-of-seeing-it-in-gravy-(7)) the clue "The importance of seeing it in gravy (7)" has been used before for the same answer, but I can't find a source for that.

Comment: I somewhat disagree with your comment. OP's riddle is semantical shorthand for "**[the answer] is** attractive when it's in gravy (7)", which does not violate your assertion (`though gravity is attractive, attractive is not gravity`). "feline inhabitant of my house" is a correct description of my cat; and it's still correct that _feline inhabitant is not my cat, but my cat is a feline inhabitant_.

Comment: @Flater the first part is not omittable. In crosswords, the definition has to match in word form with the answer, and in this case, the definition is an adjective while the answer is a noun. That makes it invalid ("It is attractive..." would have been fine, though)

Comment: @flater thanks for your comment, but could you please censor out the answer from it (via reposting) to avoid spoilers? I realised this would be contentious, which is why I appended “some people” instead of generalising. Personally, I’m not sure either way; I was just trying to answer the actual question the OP set.

Comment: @ffao It's not a crossword, it's a cryptic. The descriptions are much looser in a cryptic, by design. They do not have to be literal, nor exact.

Comment: @Flater on the contrary, all definitions in a cryptic have to follow the same rules as for valid definitions in a regular crossword, otherwise it would be unfair to the solvers. If you take any cryptic crossword in a newspaper, you'll see that the word form matching is valid for all clues.

Comment: @Flater if you just edited your comment, please do note there are still 2 instances of the answer in your comment. Also may I suggest moving to [a chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) for discussion?